# Как совместить два результата в один?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Можно ли как-то совместить два результата в один?

```js
const example = `
        SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (100.23, 234, 42) AND name LIKE 'ivan';
        INSERT INTO groups (name, tags) VALUES ('Type A1', a, type), ('group 42', group, '42')
        `;

const patterns = {
       exp: /(SELECT|FROM)/gi,
       exp2: /(INTO|INSERT)\b/gi,
}
for (let pattern in patterns) {
      let result = example.replace(patterns[pattern], "<$&></$&>");
      console.log(result);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На выходе должно быть:

```
<SELECT></SELECT> * <FROM></FROM> users WHERE id IN (100.23, 234, 42) AND name LIKE 'ivan';
<INSERT></INSERT> <INTO></INTO> groups (name, tags) VALUES ('Type A1',a, type'), ('group 42',group, 42')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
const example = `
        SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (100.23, 234, 42) AND name LIKE 'ivan';
        INSERT INTO groups (name, tags) VALUES ('Type A1', a, type), ('group 42', group, '42')
        `;

const patterns = {
       exp: /(SELECT|FROM)/gi,
       exp2: /(INTO|INSERT)\b/gi,
}

let result = example;
for (let pattern in patterns) {
      result = result.replace(patterns[pattern], "<$&></$&>");
      
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Мне нужно именно через таблицу/массив

Comment: Добавьте описание к задаче

Comment: Желаемое что вы примерно хотите из паттернов

Comment: Мне нужно совместить два результата в один. Путем перебора через for